# Convert all characters between double quotes or single quotes to ALL CAPS

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

```
$str = "Marry had \"little lamb\".SHe was very cute";
```

I want to match the string between the `""` or `''` and then make them upper case before showing in the website in PHP.

Like this:

```
Marry had "LITTLE LAMB". SHe was very cute
```

Can any one please help me out for this?

Comment: Am I the only one or has to first part nothing to do with the second part of the question? first you are talking about making everything to uppercase between quotes and the you are talking about a dot?!

Comment: It's a double question.

Comment: @Rizier123 sorry I was just trying to say that . I have tried some stuff before asking here :)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Not anymore :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can describe the content between double quotes like that:

```
"[^"]*"
```

But note that this will fail if there are escaped double quotes inside. So the way to handle them is two write:

```
"(?s:[^"\\]+|\\.)*+"
```

or in a php single quoted string:

```
$pattern = '~"(?s:[^"\\\]+|\\\.)*+"~';
```

But to be more performant, the pattern can be *unrolled* like this:

```
$pattern = '~"[^"\\\]*+(?:\\\.[^"\\\]*)*+"~';
```

To make the content uppercase, you need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) that allows to use a function as replacement:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[0]); }, $str);
```

Comment: in the line `preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[0]); }, $str)`  You have not mentioned the name of the function I mean `function ($m)` but it has to have a function name right ?

Answer (score 2):

You could achive this through `preg_replace_callback` function..

```
$str = "Marry had \"little lamb\".SHe was very cute";
echo preg_replace_callback('~"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'~', function ($m)
        { 
            return strtoupper($m[0]);
        }, $str);
```

Output:

```
Marry had "LITTLE LAMB".SHe was very cute
```

Note: I thought your input won't contain any escaped quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "Marry had \"little lamb\".SHe was very cute";

    $x = explode('"',$str);
foreach($x as $val)
{
  $y[] = ucfirst(trim($val));

}
$str = implode('.',$y);
echo $str;
```

umm... I don't understand your problem I guess i mean thats ur code just switch the . to " in the explode may you explain more if thats not ur target thank you